# Symlinks: Maven can build on one machine but not another

Tags: linux, maven, centos, symlink, gnome

I have been developing a Maven project, which builds fine on my development box. However, moving it to a server box, anything in the repo that is accessed through symlinks fails! "Package com.symlink.example does not exist"

The dev box is CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) with GNOME Shell 3.14.4.

The server box that fails is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) with no GUI.

Maven, Java are on the same versions. I'm at a loss for how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything in the repo that is accessed through symlinks fails!" Can more elaborate what that exactly means ?

Comment: Sure. Most of the Java source is in one directory, but certain files are shared with another project. There are symlinks set up inside the main directory that points to different parts of the shared folder. All of the files that are not in the main directory but are in the shared folder are treated as nonexistant in the Maven build, even though they work on the dev machine.

Comment: So you are trying to solve a thing which Maven has already solved for a long time. Symlinks are poor mans dependency management. Better solution to this having a separate maven project which produces a jar of the files and then they can be used as a dependency in any other maven build.  Apart from that I don't understand what you mean by source cause a repository does not contains source files only binary artifacts like 'jar' s..?